# A day in earth, a thousand years somewhere else

Tags: gravity, space-time

By followig the laws of physics, is it possible, that in a place far far away that one day (at that place), is counted as 1000 years in the earth.

I am familiar with black holes having impact on time. But would it be possible without black holes and such,

I think i've heard that the gravity has impact with the time too?

Comment: You should clarify your question. Title says: "A day in earth, a thousand years somewhere else" whereas description states "one day (at that place), is counted as 1000 years in the earth".

Comment: I am curious, would this have anything to do with the following verse: 2 Peter 3:8 But, beloved, be not ignorant of this one thing, that one day is with the Lord as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day.

Comment: @Jonathan no actually not :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean a *day* in terms of an Earth day in both cases, the phenomenon I believe you're referring to is called [*time dilation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation), which affects the speed at which time is experienced by one body relative to another. This rate is affected by velocity and gravity, each of which can cause the bending of spacetime that results in the discrepancy between objects. Both gravity and velocity slow one's time as they increase.

The situation you describe is *probably* not naturally occurring, however is not outside the realm of reality.  As referenced by Wiki from Calder's book [Magic Universe](http://books.google.com/books?id=kbPmQX-OoBgC&pg=PA378), Calder claims that an acceleration of a constant 1G (what we feel on Earth all the time) would result in the affects of time dilation allowing you to traverse the entirety of the known universe in a single human lifetime (for the traveler). Conversely, during your trip, the rest of the universe would be aging 'normally'. There are plenty of technical problems with the feasibility of achieving this, but is conceptually possible.

I'm not particularly qualified to explain the equations behind it, so I'll leave that to our more capable members. Coincidentally, time dilation is the excuse I give when asked why I walk so quickly.

Comment: How do you use the argument for walking quickly?

Comment: It's something of a cheeky response to the question, by travelling faster I experience time more slowly and will thus age more slowly. Of course, the reality is that this is totally negligible.

Comment: That's a smart way of fooling someone. Do people believe it?

Comment: Mostly it's just silliness with coworkers. They have no idea what I'm talking about, but the tone of my workplace is rather light, so there is a lot of joking like this.